# Add a Counter to the title of the Send-MailMessage

Tags: powershell

I want to add a counter, so the number of tickets send will increase by 1 every time an email is sent. I had it working on another powershell script but on this one, seems that something is wrong. Maybe someone can give me a hand with this:

Edit: The counter displays always #1, after every email sent.

```
if ($Counter -eq $null){

$Counter = 1
}

$Email       = "test"
$Internal    = ""
$Subject     = "Error #$Counter - Test - $(Get-Date -format dd/MM/yy)"

[array]$attachments = Get-ChildItem "path"

if ([array]$attachments -eq $null) {
}

else {

$Msg = @{
    to          = $Email
    cc          = $Internal
    from        = "someone"
    Body        = 'body'
    subject     = "$Subject"
    smtpserver  = "server"
    BodyAsHtml  = $True
    Attachments = $attachments.fullname

}

Send-MailMessage @Msg

$Counter++

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are evaluating your string too early.  Try removing this line: `$Subject     = "Error #$Counter - Test - $(Get-Date -format dd/MM/yy)"`, then change `subject     = "$Subject"` to `subject     = "Error #$Counter - Test - $(Get-Date -format dd/MM/yy)"`.

Comment: Also, if this is not in a loop, you may need to use `$Global:Counter` instead of `$Counter`

Comment: Not working. i have to set every `$Counter` as `$Global:Counter`? cuz i did that. I have a little knowledge yet of power shell, so still learning this things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the counter to always increase, you can store it in the registry or store it in a text file like so:

```
if(-not(Test-Path C:\PathTo\Counter.txt)){
   1 > C:\PathTo\Counter.txt #create the file with a default counter
}
$TicketCounter = [int](Get-Content C:\PathTo\Counter.txt)

#restOfYourScriptHere
$TicketCounter++ #as needed to increment

#end of your Script

$TicketCounter > C:\PathTo\Counter.txt  #saves the new counter value
```

Comment: Well, that is a simple solution that i did not think of. Works great! Thank you for help, and i will though of this things in the future to test out.

Comment: You could always do the registry too, but for something like this, storing into a text file is just so easy, and you can also get the benefit of opening the text file in Notepad++ and see it increment in real time, or reset it with a different process. The registry is just a tiny bit harder though, so that's why I suggested this route.  Plus you get the perk of being able to store the counter in the same directory as your script, for added ease of organization.